# undefined reference to memdup

Tags: c, libraries

I've got 5 files in a directory. I'm trying to compile my program using `gcc -o mini2.c -pthread -utils`and I am getting the following error:

```
/tmp/cc2W2ocr.o: In function `fifo_put':
mini2.c:(.text+0x59): undefined reference to `memdup'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Any ideas how I can make that memdup function visible to the compiler?** The files I have in the directory are:

- mini2.c

  ```
          // Mini Assignment 1
          // Author: Georges Krinker
          // Student #: 260369844
          // Course: ECSE 427 (OS)


          #include <stdio.h>
          #include <stdlib.h>

          extern char etext, edata,end;
          int not_init;
          int init =10;
          int dat =20;

          int main(void){

              char *stack = (char*)alloca(10000);
              int pid;
              char *dynamic_var = (char*)malloc(4000);
              int c =0;
              FILE *file;
              char l[8000];
              int len=8000;
              char s [1200];

              // To find where the stack is we use the start of the last declared local variable s.
              // This is because of the LIFO nature of the stack
              // For a more accurate look at proc/pid/smaps and see the stack range (Readme.html)


              printf("The stack starts approx. at %p\n", &s[1200]);

              printf("The stack ends at %p\n\n", stack-10000);

              // The most reliable way to obtain the Memory mapping segment is to read
              // the proc/pid/maps file. (see Readme.html)

              printf("The entire memory mapping segment spans:\n");

              sprintf(s, "/proc/%d/maps", pid=getpid());

              file = fopen(s, "r");
              if (file) {
                  //skip first 4 lines of the maps file
                  fgets(l, len, file);
                  fgets(l, len, file);
                  fgets(l, len, file);
                  fgets(l, len, file);
                  fgets(l, len, file);
                  while (c <= 9) {
                     fgets(l, len, file);
                     fputs ( l, stdout ); /*print the memeory mapping segments */
                  c++;
                 }
              }
               fclose(file);

              // Use the start of the dyn. allocated variable for the start of the heap.
              // There is a 8 byte offset that I noticed when comparing my obtained
              // address with the process's smap file which is why I subtract 8. (See Readme.html)

              printf("\n\nThe Heap segment starts at %p\n", dynamic_var-8);

              // Add the size of that variable to the start address to get the end of the heap

              printf("The heap ends at %p\n\n", dynamic_var+100-8);

              // Use the symbol edata to find the start of BSS

              printf("The BSS segment starts after %10p \n\n", &edata);

              // The end of text and start of data is the location of
              // the single initialized global variable init.

              printf("The data segment starts at %10p\n\n", &init);

              //Use the address of main for the start of text.
              // For a more accurate number, do objdump -x <filename> and
              // look for .text in the <filename> section (see Readme.html)

              printf("The start of text is approximately at %p\n\n", main);

              printf("For more info, check the comments of this source code and the Readme.html\n\n");


              return 0;

          }
  ```
- utils.c

  ```
      /* source: utils.c */
      /* Copyright Gerhard Rieger 2001-2009 */
      /* Published under the GNU General Public License V.2, see file COPYING */

      /* useful additions to C library */

      #include "config.h"

      #include "sysincludes.h"

      #include "compat.h" /* socklen_t */
      #include "mytypes.h"
      #include "sycls.h"
      #include "utils.h"


      #if !HAVE_MEMRCHR
      /* GNU extension, available since glibc 2.1.91 */
      void *memrchr(const void *s, int c, size_t n) {
         const unsigned char *t = ((unsigned char *)s)+n;
         while (--t >= (unsigned char *)s) {
            if (*t == c)  break;
         }
         if (t < (unsigned char *)s)
            return NULL;
         return (void *)t;
      }
      #endif /* !HAVE_MEMRCHR */

      void *memdup(const void *src, size_t n) {
         void *dest;

         if ((dest = Malloc(n)) == NULL) {
            return NULL;
         }

         memcpy(dest, src, n);
         return dest;
      }

      /* search the keyword-table for a match of the leading part of name. */
      /* returns the pointer to the matching field of the keyword or NULL if no
         keyword was found. */
      const struct wordent *keyw(const struct wordent *keywds, const char *name, unsigned int nkeys) {
         unsigned int lower, upper, mid;
         int r;

         lower = 0;
         upper = nkeys;

         while (upper - lower > 1)
         {
            mid = (upper + lower) >> 1;
            if (!(r = strcasecmp(keywds[mid].name, name)))
            {
           return &keywds[mid];
            }
            if (r < 0)
           lower = mid;
            else
           upper = mid;
         }
         if (nkeys > 0 && !(strcasecmp(keywds[lower].name, name)))
         {
            return &keywds[lower];
         }
         return NULL;
      }

      /* Linux: setenv(), AIX: putenv() */
      #if !HAVE_SETENV
      int setenv(const char *name, const char *value, int overwrite) {
         int result;
         char *env;
         if (!overwrite) {
            if (getenv(name))  return 0;  /* already exists */
         }
         if ((env = Malloc(strlen(name)+strlen(value)+2)) == NULL) {
            return -1;
         }
         sprintf(env, "%s=%s", name, value);
         if ((result = putenv(env)) != 0) {   /* AIX docu says "... nonzero ..." */
            free(env);
            result = -1;
         }
         /* linux "man putenv" says: ...this string becomes part of the environment*/
         return result;
      }
      #endif /* !HAVE_SETENV */



      /* sanitize an "untrusted" character. output buffer must provide at least 5
         characters space.
         Does not append null. returns length out output (currently: max 4) */
      static size_t sanitize_char(char c, char *o, int style) {
         int hn;  /* high nibble */
         int ln;  /* low nibble */
         int n;   /* written chars */
         if (isprint(c)) {
            *o = c;
            return 1;
         }
         *o++ = '\\';
         n = 2;
         switch (c) {
         case '\0': *o++ = '0';  break;
         case '\a': *o++ = 'a';  break;
         case '\b': *o++ = 'b';  break;
         case '\t': *o++ = 't';  break;
         case '\n': *o++ = 'n';  break;
         case '\v': *o++ = 'v';  break;
         case '\f': *o++ = 'f';  break;
         case '\r': *o++ = 'r';  break;
         case '\'': *o++ = '\''; break;
         case '\"': *o++ = '"';  break;
         case '\\': *o++ = '\\'; break;
         default:
            *o++ = 'x';
            hn = (c>>4)&0x0f;
            ln = c&0x0f;
            *o++ = (hn>=10 ? (('A'-1)+(hn-10)) : ('0'+hn));
            *o++ = (ln>=10 ? (('A'-1)+(ln-10)) : ('0'+ln));
            n = 4;
         }
         return n;
      }

      /* sanitize "untrusted" text, replacing special control characters with the C
         string version ("\x"), and replacing unprintable chars with ".".
         text can grow to four times of input, so keep output buffer long enough!
         returns a pointer to the first untouched byte of the output buffer.
      */
      char *sanitize_string(const char *data, /* input data */
                 size_t bytes,    /* length of input data, >=0 */
                 char *coded, /* output buffer, must be long enough */
                 int style
                 ) {
         int c;

         while (bytes > 0) {
            c = *(unsigned char *)data++;
            coded += sanitize_char(c, coded, style);
            --bytes;
         }
         return coded;
      }

      /* copies a substring out of a given buff
         returns scratch, \0 terminated; scratch must provide len+1 bytes
      */
      char *xiosubstr(char *scratch, const char *str, size_t from, size_t len) {
         char *scratch0 = scratch;
         str += from;
         while (len--) {
            *scratch++ = *str++;
         }
         *scratch = '\0';
         return scratch0;
      }
  ```
- utils.h

  ```
                          /* source: utils.h */
          /* Copyright Gerhard Rieger 2001-2008 */
          /* Published under the GNU General Public License V.2, see file COPYING                   */

          #ifndef __utils_h_included
          #define __utils_h_included 1

          /* a generic name table entry */
          struct wordent {
             const char *name;
             void *desc;
          } ;

          #if !HAVE_MEMRCHR
          extern void *memrchr(const void *s, int c, size_t n);
          #endif
          extern void *memdup(const void *src, size_t n);
          #if !HAVE_SETENV
          extern int setenv(const char *name, const char *value, int overwrite);
          #endif /* !HAVE_SETENV */

          extern const struct wordent *keyw(const struct wordent *keywds, const char *name, unsigned int nkeys);


          #define XIOSAN_ZERO_MASK                  0x000f
          #define XIOSAN_ZERO_DEFAULT               0x0000
          #define XIOSAN_ZERO_DOT                   0x0001
          #define XIOSAN_ZERO_BACKSLASH_OCT_3       0x0002
          #define XIOSAN_ZERO_BACKSLASH_OCT_4       0x0003
          #define XIOSAN_ZERO_BACKSLASHX_HEX_UP     0x0004
          #define XIOSAN_ZERO_BACKSLASHX_HEX_LOW    0x0005
          #define XIOSAN_ZERO_PERCENT_HEX_UP        0x0006
          #define XIOSAN_ZERO_PERCENT_HEX_LOW       0x0007
          #define XIOSAN_CONTROL_MASK               0x00f0
          #define XIOSAN_CONTROL_DEFAULT            0x0000
          #define XIOSAN_CONTROL_DOT                0x0010
          #define XIOSAN_CONTROL_BACKSLASH_OCT_3    0x0020
          #define XIOSAN_CONTROL_BACKSLASH_OCT_4    0x0030
          #define XIOSAN_CONTROL_BACKSLASHX_HEX_UP  0x0040
          #define XIOSAN_CONTROL_BACKSLASHX_HEX_LOW 0x0050
          #define XIOSAN_CONTROL_PERCENT_HEX_UP     0x0060
          #define XIOSAN_CONTROL_PERCENT_HEX_LOW    0x0070
          #define XIOSAN_UNPRINT_MASK               0x0f00
          #define XIOSAN_UNPRINT_DEFAULT            0x0000
          #define XIOSAN_UNPRINT_DOT                0x0100
          #define XIOSAN_UNPRINT_BACKSLASH_OCT_3    0x0200
          #define XIOSAN_UNPRINT_BACKSLASH_OCT_4    0x0300
          #define XIOSAN_UNPRINT_BACKSLASHX_HEX_UP  0x0400
          #define XIOSAN_UNPRINT_BACKSLASHX_HEX_LOW 0x0500
          #define XIOSAN_UNPRINT_PERCENT_HEX_UP     0x0600
          #define XIOSAN_UNPRINT_PERCENT_HEX_LOW    0x0700
          #define XIOSAN_DEFAULT_MASK               0xf000
          #define XIOSAN_DEFAULT_BACKSLASH_DOT      0x1000
          #define XIOSAN_DEFAULT_BACKSLASH_OCT_3    0x2000
          #define XIOSAN_DEFAULT_BACKSLASH_OCT_4    0x3000
          #define XIOSAN_DEFAULT_BACKSLASHX_HEX_UP  0x4000
          #define XIOSAN_DEFAULT_BACKSLASHX_HEX_LOW 0x5000
          #define XIOSAN_DEFAULT_PERCENT_HEX_UP     0x6000
          #define XIOSAN_DEFAULT_PERCENT_HEX_LOW    0x7000

          extern
          char *sanitize_string(const char *data, /* input data */
                     size_t bytes,    /* length of input data, >=0 */
                     char *coded, /* output buffer, must be long enough */
                     int style);
          extern
          char *xiosubstr(char *scratch, const char *str, size_t from, size_t len);

          #endif /* !defined(__utils_h_included) */
  ```
- fifo.c

  ```
                          /*
           * fifo.c
           *
           * A simple FIFO implementation.
           *
           * Copyright (C) 2010, Marek Polacek <xpolac06@stud.fit.vutbr.cz>
           */

          #include <stdio.h>
          #include <stdlib.h>
          #include <string.h>
          #include "fifo.h"
          #include "utils.h"

          void fifo_put(fifo_t *fifo, char *data, size_t size)
          {   
              struct item *i;
              i = malloc(sizeof(*i));
              if (!i) {
                  perror("malloc");
                  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
              }

              if (size) {
                  data = memdup(data, size);
                  if (!data) {
                      fputs("fatal: out of memory\n", stderr);
                      free(i);
                      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                  }
              }

              i->next = NULL;
              i->buf = data;

              if (!fifo->tail) {
                  fifo->head = i;
                  fifo->tail = i;
              } else {
                  fifo->tail->next = i;
                  fifo->tail = i;
              }
          }

          char *fifo_get(fifo_t *fifo)
          {
              struct item *i;
              char *data;

              assert(fifo != NULL);
              if (fifo_empty(fifo))
                  return NULL;

              i = fifo->head;
              data = i->buf;

              fifo->head = i->next;
              if (!fifo->head)
                  fifo->tail = NULL;
              free(i);

              return data;
          }

          void fifo_free(fifo_t *fifo)
          {
              assert(fifo != NULL);
              while (fifo->head)
                  (void) fifo_get(fifo);
              free(fifo);
          }

          fifo_t *fifo_init(void)
          {
              fifo_t *fifo;
              fifo = malloc(sizeof(*fifo));
              if (!fifo) {
                  perror("malloc");
                  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
              }

              fifo->head = NULL;
              fifo->tail = NULL;
              return fifo;
          }
  ```
- fifo.h

  ```
                          /*
           * fifo.h
           *
           * A simple FIFO implementation.
           *
           * Copyright (C) 2010, Marek Polacek <xpolac06@stud.fit.vutbr.cz>
           */

          #ifndef FIFO_H
          #define FIFO_H

          #include <assert.h>

          struct item {
              char *buf;
              struct item *next;
          }; 

          struct fifo {
              struct item *head;
              struct item *tail;
          };

          typedef struct fifo fifo_t;

          extern fifo_t *fifo_init(void);
          extern void fifo_free(fifo_t *);
          extern char *fifo_get(fifo_t *);
          extern void fifo_put(fifo_t *, char *, size_t);

          static inline int fifo_empty(fifo_t *fifo)
          {
              return (fifo->head == NULL);
          }

          static inline char *fifo_peek(fifo_t *fifo)
          {
              assert(fifo != NULL);
              if (!fifo_empty(fifo))
                  return fifo->head->buf;
              else
                  return NULL;
          }

          #endif  /* FIFO_H */
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The current invocation of the compiler simply doesn't make sense (writing the output to a C file? What is `-util`?). [Read something up on C compilation](http://www.tenouk.com/ModuleW.html). You need to link together all the object files, so something like

```
gcc -o myprog myprog.c util.c
```

would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Your gcc commandline is not quite right.
Try something like:

`gcc *.c -o mini2`

Or you could compile them individually first and then link together:

`gcc -c fifo.c
gcc -c utils.c
gcc -c mini2.c
gcc -o mini2 mini2.o fifo.o utils.o`

You might want to read about compiling and linking with gcc and ld.